# Access 'self' within an object when other arguments are also commited (perl)

Tags: perl, oop

I get an error message while trying to access `$self` and other variables in a `sub` inside an object. When the `sub` is called from outside the object everything works fine. But when I try to access it within the object I get an error (see below).

Here is an example code describing my problem:

```
package input;
use warnings;
use strict;

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = { };  
    $self->{_name} = shift;
    bless ($self, $class);
    return $self;
}

sub test1{
    my $self = shift;
    my $person = shift;
    return $self->{_name}." and ".$person;
}

sub test2{
    my $self = shift;
    my $person = shift;
    print test1($self,$person);
}

package Main;
use warnings;
use strict;

my $i = input->new("Jon");
print $i->test1("Me")."\n";
$i->test2();
```

The call for print `$i->test1("Me")."\n";` does work fine.

I like to access `test1()` within a different function inside the object.
But for `$i->test2();` I get the error

> Use of uninitiated value $person in concatenation (.) or String at Line 22.

If I would write

```
sub test2{
    my $self = shift;
    my $person = "Jim";

    print test1($self,$person);
}
```

It would work, too.

But I **explicitly** want to pass some other Variables to the `sub` besides `$self`. Since I want to use `$self` and the other variables. I think it has something to do with passing `$self` to the `sub` or not, but I can't figure out how to access `$self` without the `my $self = shift;` command.

Comment: `my($self,$person) = @_;` is the more modern way to get the values out of [`@_`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%40_). ( [`shift`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift.html) without an argument removes the first value of [`@_`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%40_) and returns it ) It should also be faster on newer versions of Perl.

Comment: Thanx Brad, I did change that, too. It took some time for me to understand the lists and their possibilities in Perl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Use of uninitiated value $person in concatenation (.) or String at Line 22.

When calling `test2` method you've forgot `$person` argument, ie.

```
$i->test2();
```

should be

```
$i->test2("Someone");
```